# JQuery selector for free floating text node

Tags: jquery, cheerio

How would one select only the 'foo' text (and not the span) in this example?

```
<div class="bar">foo
    <span>...</span>
</div>
```

Alternatively, what would your search query to figure this out be? I'm at a loss...

Answer (score 1):

With JQuery & cheerio, it seems one can use :

```
$('div.bar').contents()[0]
```

src: [How do I select text nodes with jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/298750/how-do-i-select-text-nodes-with-jquery)